# jquery on click is not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, attributes

I am updating/add data attribute on ajax success. But the problem is that I am getting the updated value using on click handler.

Ajax success update value.

```
            success: function(data) {            
               if (data) {
                  var max = container.find('.xyz').data('max');
                  rooty.attr('data-max', max);
                }
            }
```

I am not getting the updated value on click.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.ash_loadmore:not(.disabled)', function(event) {
       var me = $(this);
       var button = me.parent().parent();
       var cat = button.data('max');
    });
```

I already have this markup

```
<div class="container" data-max="5"></div>
```

I am just updating the value(5) using ajax success callback. Though it update the value but I am still getting the original value (5) not the updated one.

Comment: You're not actually using the data you get from the Ajax call, you're just assigning the *max* from the element with class *.xyz* to the *rooty* element when the call is successful

Comment: I am just updating the max value using ajax call .

Comment: Then your question is missing the crucial parts of your code, the max value in the code you included is not updated from an Ajax quest. You are just checking if `data`, which comes from an Ajax request is truthy, and if it is, you totally ignore that data and set the max value from an element's data attribute

Comment: I have no problem with ajax, my on click event is not returning updated data-max value, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rooty.attr('data-max', max);
```

You are intermixing your usage of `data()` and `attr()`.  The way jQuery works, once you call `data(key)` it will cache that value, for performance sake.  If at a later time, the value is changed with `attr()`, the internal jQuery cache is not updated, so subsequent calls to `data(key)` will return what was in the cache.

To avoid this, stick with getting and setting data attributes with the `data()` method, as setting the value with `data(key, value)` does update the internal cache.

```
rooty.data('max'); //getter
rooty.data('max', max); //setter
```

```js
var $div = $('div');

console.log($div.attr('data-key'));
console.log($div.data('key'));

$div.attr('data-key', 'two');
console.log($div.attr('data-key')); //prints 'two' as that is the attr value
console.log($div.data('key')); //prints 'one' as that's the cache value

$div.data('key', 'three');
console.log($div.attr('data-key')); //prints 'two' as that's still the attr value
console.log($div.data('key')); //prints 'three' as that's the cache value
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="one"></div>
```